# Getting basename and notdir to work in prerequisite (dependency) list

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to write a `Makefile` to make generating some figures
automatic and efficient.

My figures are generated in `../thesis/figures` using Octave `.m`
files that are in the current directory where the `Makefile` also is.
Each `.m` file, e.g. `figure1.m`, may generate several figures, e.g.
`figure1.p1.tex` and `figure1.p2.tex` (and their dependecies, which
are also generated by `figure1.m`). These `.tex` files are then to be compiled using LaTeX (a single run of `pdflatex figure1.p1.tex` suffices in this case; so, there is no need for `latexmk` or other alternatives).

The `Makefile` I have so far is

```
OCTAVE = octave --jit-compiler --no-gui --quiet
PDFLATEX = pdflatex

FIGDIR = ../thesis/figures
TEXTARGETS = $(wildcard $(FIGDIR)/*.tex)

.PHONY: figures
figures: $(TEXTARGETS)

$(TEXTARGETS): %.tex : $(basename $(notdir %)).m
       $(OCTAVE) $<
       $(PDFLATEX) $@
```

What I'm trying to do in the prerequisite (dependency) rule is just to convert `../thesis/figures/figure1.p1.tex` to `figure1.m`, because the former depends on the latter. Then, if the `.tex` is older than the `.m`, the recipie is supposed to run `$(OCTAVE)` on `figure1.m` and then `$(PDFLATEX)` on `../thesis/figures/figure1.p1.tex` to recompile and update the figure.

But doing a dry-run with `make -n`, I get the message

```
make: *** No rule to make target `../thesis/figures/figure1.p1.m', needed by `../thesis/figures/figure1.p1.tex'.  Stop.
```

which, as far as I can tell, means that the `basename` and `notdir` functions are not being run by `make`. I suspect this may have to do with them being in the prerequisite list (I know for example that `$@` expands to empty when in the prerequisite list). I tried using a `.SECONDEXPANSION:`, https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html, thinking that maybe the following would work

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(TEXTARGETS): % : $(basename $(notdir $$@)).m
       $(OCTAVE) $<
       $(PDFLATEX) $@
```

But it doesn't and I get the same message.

I'm running `GNU Make 3.81`. What am I doing wrong? Do you have any suggestions to do this task better?

**Edit**
Originally, I thought `basename` removes everything after the first `.` in filename (inclusive of `.`). However, it removes only the last `.` and everything after that (and disregards `.`s in directory names). So, for it to work with my file names, the above, after including the correction in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31105973/2636530 below, has to be

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(TEXTARGETS): %.tex : $$(basename $$(notdir %)).m
       $(OCTAVE) $<
       $(PDFLATEX) $@
```

This way, with the target being `../thesis/figures/figure1.p1.tex`, `%` captures, and expands to only `../thesis/figures/figure1.p1`, and then `basename` and `notdir` do their job after second expansion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the `$(basename)` and `$(notdir)` calls too (i.e. `$$(basename)` and `$$(notdir)`. (The way the `$$(patsubst)` call is escaped in the secondary expansion section of the manual you linked to.)

Without doing that those calls are evaluated against an argument of `$$@` during the initial expansion phase and you end up with `$$@` being all that's left for the secondary expansion phase.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I had forgotton to escape those calls. This solves the problem.