# Treat multiple targets in Makefile as one entity and ignore non-existent prerequisite

Tags: makefile

This question is based on another question of mine here: [Getting basename and notdir to work in prerequisite (dependency) list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31105435/getting-basename-and-notdir-to-work-in-prerequisite-dependency-list).

I'm using a `Makefile` to generate some figures automatically and
efficiently.

My figures are generated in `../thesis/figures` using Octave `.m`
files that are in the current directory where the `Makefile` also is.
Each `.m` file, e.g. `figure1.m`, may generate several figures, e.g.
`figure1.p1.tex` and `figure1.p2.tex` (and their dependecies, which
are also generated by `figure1.m`). These `.tex` files are then to be compiled using LaTeX (a single run of `pdflatex figure1.p1.tex` suffices in this case; so, there is no need for `latexmk` or other alternatives).

The `Makefile` I have so far is

```
OCTAVE = octave --jit-compiler --no-gui --quiet
PDFLATEX = pdflatex

FIGDIR = ../thesis/figures
TEXTARGETS = $(wildcard $(FIGDIR)/*.tex)

.PHONY: figures
figures: $(TEXTARGETS)


.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(TEXTARGETS): %.tex : $$(basename $$(notdir %)).m
   $(OCTAVE) $<
   $(PDFLATEX) $@
```

A dry run with `make -n` shows me

```
octave --jit-compiler --no-gui --quiet figure1.m
pdflatex ../thesis/figures/figure1.p1.tex
octave --jit-compiler --no-gui --quiet figure1.m
pdflatex ../thesis/figures/figure1.p2.tex
make: *** No rule to make target `figure2.m', needed by `../thesis/figures/figure2.tex'.  Stop.
```

There are two issues here:

1) Both `figure1.p1.tex` and `figure.p2.tex` are generated by the first run of `figure1.m` by `octave`. Is there a way to treat all targets with the same basename (or other pattern) as a prerequisite as one, so that there is no more than one invocation of `octave` per `.m` file?

2) `figure2.tex` was made using some other means than an `.m` file. How can I tell make to ignore a rule if its prerequisite does not exist. I know how to do that for an explicit prerequisite:

```
target: prereq
    recipe

prereq:
```

But what to do in this case with the prerequisite being derived from the target's name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU make can be taught that multiple targets are created by one command invocation by using a pattern rule for those targets.

From [Pattern Rule Examples](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Examples):

> This pattern rule has two targets:
>
> ```
> %.tab.c %.tab.h: %.y
>     bison -d $<
> ```
>
> This tells make that the recipe ‘bison -d x.y’ will make both x.tab.c and x.tab.h. If the file foo depends on the files parse.tab.o and scan.o and the file scan.o depends on the file parse.tab.h, when parse.y is changed, the recipe ‘bison -d parse.y’ will be executed only once, and the prerequisites of both parse.tab.o and scan.o will be satisfied. (Presumably the file parse.tab.o will be recompiled from parse.tab.c and the file scan.o from scan.c, while foo is linked from parse.tab.o, scan.o, and its other prerequisites, and it will execute happily ever after.)

So you could use something like

```
figure1.%1.tex figure1.%2.tex: figure1.m
        $(OCTAVE) $<
```

but to do that for `N` output files where `N` is variable would require generating an included makefile that pulled that information out of the `.m` file (or similar).

If a file exists that matches a target but no matching prerequisite file is found make will just use the file it found and ignore the rule (the rule doesn't apply). You shouldn't have to do anything for that.

If, however, the file would otherwise match the rule (but you don't want make to follow the rule for that file) then you can cancel just that application by giving that file an explicit target. Like this.

```
figure2.tex: ;
```

Comment: Pattern rules, as you mention, are helpful for a fixed set of targets. I will accept this answer if no one else has a better suggestion. As of now, I'm considering using a generated makefile and including it, as you suggested, but it seems overkill for such a basic task.

Comment: Generated makefiles are more complicated in concept then in practice and work very well for many things (I use them for all sorts of complicated generated tasks at work). There's no way to add targets to a given rule or teach make that extra targets come from a single rule other than the listed pattern rule support. You could go with [atomic rules](http://www.cmcrossroads.com/article/atomic-rules-gnu-make) instead if you preferred (but that requires not using the specific files as prerequisites).